# Saving variables to onsavedinstance and determine whether or not they aren't null

Tags: android, android-layout

**What would be the best way to only save strings/images from existing ImageViews/TextBoxes depending on the layout file? Should I just check what layout I'm currently using (using the contentView variable) and based on that save from those existing TextBoxes or ?**

So I have 4 Layouts for both Landscape and Portrait:

1. main.xml (Choose between select image from SD or from application itself)
2. imagefromsd.xml (Corresponding layout for SD)
3. imagefromapplication (Corresponding layout for application)
4. finishandupload.xml (Where I display the result and give option to save/upload image)

So the problem is I get nullpointer exceptions when switching between landscape and portrait I use `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and `protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

This happens because I save strings from textboxes and images from ImageViews, but not every layout file has all textboxes, so when I try to save a string from an unexisting textbox I get nullpointer exceptions.

Right now I'm saving the current contentView in a variable when I change the setContentView.

```
    public void ShowLoadAPP(View v){ //Leave menu and show view for images from application
    setContentView(R.layout.imagefromapplication);
    contentView = R.layout.imagefromapplication;
    LoadDrawables(); //Load list with images and show the first image
}

public void ShowLoadSD(View v){ //Leave menu and show view for images from sd
    setContentView(R.layout.imagefromsd);
    contentView = R.layout.imagefromsd;
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(savedInstanceState.getInt("MyView"));
    //Lines where application crashes because of nullpointer where the retrieved string doesn't exist.

    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMeme)).setImageResource(savedInstanceState.getInt("MyImage"));
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtImageTop)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("MyTopString"));
    ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtImageButtom)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("MyButtomString"));
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgMemeFinished)).setImageBitmap((Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("MyBitmap"));
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    contentView = contentView == null ? R.layout.menu : contentView;
    selectedImage = selectedImage == null ? R.drawable.are_you_fucking_kidding : selectedImage;
    stringTop = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtImageTop)).getText().toString() == null ? "" : ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtImageTop)).getText().toString();
    stringButtom = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtImageButtom)).getText().toString() == null ? "" : ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtImageButtom)).getText().toString();
    combinedImage = combinedImage;
    outState.putInt("MyView", contentView);
    outState.putInt("MyImage", selectedImage);
    outState.putString("MyTopString", stringTop);
    outState.putString("MyButtomString", stringButtom);
    outState.putParcelable("MyBitmap", combinedImage);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMemeFinished"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imgMemeFinishedDescription" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:onClick="SaveImage"
    android:text="@string/btnSave" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnUpload"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:onClick="UploadImage"
    android:text="@string/btnUpload" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgMeme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imgMemeDescription" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtImageTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@string/txtImageTop" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtImageButtom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@string/txtImageButtom" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPreviousImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:onClick="PreviousImage"
    android:text="@string/btnPreviousImage" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNextImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:onClick="NextImage"
    android:text="@string/btnNextImage" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFinish"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:onClick="ShowFinish"
    android:text="@string/btnFinish" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use different activities for different screens.
If you plan to include all the layout in the same activity put them on the same xml file, otherwise use different activities and a layout on each of them. To communicate and send data across activities you can put information within your Intent, or if you need more complex info use persistent memory (DB, sharedpreferences, others).

Comment: Rewrote the application with intents instead of 1 activity and now its fine. Hoped I didn't have to but oh well :P